Finding a Subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ with Only Trivial Homomorphisms from $\mathbb{Q}$ to $H$
I am looking for a subgroup $  H  $ of $ \mathbb{Q} $ (the group of rational numbers under addition) such that the only homomorphism from $ \mathbb{Q}$ to $  H  $ is the trivial homomorphism. I have tried subgroups such as $\left  \{\frac{j}{2^k}:j,k\in\mathbb Z \right \} $ and other subgroups, but all have non-trivial homomorphisms. Is there a subgroup with the desired property or I'm walking in a circle ?

MathJax does not recognize the $\LaTeX$ delimiters \(, \), \[, and \]. You should use $....$ for in-line formulas and $$...$$ for displayed formulas.

@ArturoMagidin thank you

Maybe I'm missing something, but are you sure there are non-trivial homomorphisms into the subgroup you describe? What is an example of such a homomorphism?

To follow up on my previous comment, suppose $h(1) = \frac{J}{2^K}$, reduced so that $J$ is odd or $K = 1$. What then could $h(\frac{1}{3J})$ be?

Any subgroup $H$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ which does not contain non-trivial divisible subgroups will do. In particular, $H=\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup with no morphism $\mathbb{Q}\to \mathbb{Z}$.
To verify the latter, let $f\colon\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be a group homomorphism, and let $q\in \mathbb{Q}$. Then for every positive integer $n$ there exists a rational $r$ such that $nr=q$. Then
$$f(q) = f(nr) = nf(r),$$
so $f(q)$ is an integer that is divisible by $n$ for every positive integer $n$. That means that $f(q)=0$. Thus, $f$ is trivial.
